# ¿Cómo centrar una tabla, usando Bootstrap y CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo una página para registrar usuarios y estoy encriptando las contraseñas que se ingresan, los usuarios se muestran en una sección de la página y todos los que estén registrados se van listando en una tabla, pero tengo un problema con la visibilidad de dicha tabla, ya que desde que empecé a encriptar las contraseñas, la contraseña encriptada; queda de unos 60 dígitos más o menos y hace que la tabla se desplace y se pegue al margen derecho de la página dejando mucho espacio del lado izquierdo. Lo que quiero es lograr centrar la tabla para que no quede dicho espacio y se vea mejor.

El código que tengo en mi plantilla HTML es el siguiente:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body{
                background:#0F3E45;
                font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 600;
            }
            h1{
                color:white;

            }
            h3{
                color:white;
            }
            p{
                color:white;
            }
            th{
                color:white;
            }
            td{
                color:white;
            }
            nav ul{
                position:relative;
                margin:auto;
                width:50%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            nav ul li{
                display:inline-block;
                width:24%;
                line-height: 50px;
                list-style: none;
            }
            nav ul li a{
                color:white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            nav ul li a:hover{
                color:green;
                text-decoration: none;          
            }
            section{
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                width:400px;
            }
            .form-group{
                padding: 0;
            } 
            .navbar-dark .navbar-brand:hover{
                color:lightblue;
                text-decoration: none;

            }
            section form input#usuarioRegistro{
                text-transform: lowercase;
            }
            section h2{
                color:white;
                position: relative;
                margin:auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            table{
                position:relative;
                margin:auto;
                width:100%;
                left:-15%;
            }
            table thead tr th{
                padding:10px;
            }
            table tbody tr td{
                padding:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "modules/navegacion.php"; ?>
    <section>
    <?php 
    $mvc = new MvcController();
    $mvc -> enlacesPaginasController();
     ?>
    </section>
    <script src="views/js/validarRegistro.js"></script> 
    <script src="views/js/validarIngreso.js"></script> 
    <script src="views/js/validarEdicion.js"></script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

En mi vista donde se muestran lo susuarios tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-12 ">
                    <h2>USUARIOS</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class=row>
                    <div class="col" >
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Contraseña</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Editar</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Borrar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $b=new MvcController();
                                $b->vistaUsuariosController();
                                $b->borrarUsuarioController();
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Cabe destacar que la tabla la estoy llenando desde una base de datos...**

Dejo una imagen de cómo se ve la tabla para que puedan entender lo que me ocurre.

[image: Asi se ve la tabla]

PD. Ya intenté colocando:

```
 table{ 
    margin: auto; 
 }
```

Pero no me funcionó y la tabla sigue quedando en la misma posición. 
Si alguien sabe qué puedo cambiar para que funcione, sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Al margen del código que ya tienes, considero deberías ocupar solo las clases que ya provee el framework para tales efectos; entonces has esto:

Me parece bootstrap posee una clase predefinida que trabaja por debajo con flexbox para centrar contenido horizontalmente con la propiedad `justify-content` de este modo:

```
.justify-content-center
```

Que se lo pudieras aplicar a un `div` que envuelva a toda la tabla

Revisa [este enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)

Comment: Perefecto!! muchas gracias con esto se soluciona el problema, Crack!!

Comment: @Jesús la vista de tu tabla no está dentro de una sección?

Comment: @JheymanMejia había entendido mal la prengunta, todas las vistas están dentro del <section> en la plantilla html, aunque en la vista como tal no le pongo <section>

Comment: @Jesús pues entonces ese es tu error, estás asignando un ancho de 400px a todo lo que esté dentro de ese `<section>`, y a menos que hayas cambiado a `position: absolute` su contenido, no entiendo cómo hiciste para resolver el problema sin eliminar ese ancho... pero bueno.

Comment: @JheymanMejia, bueno el section en css lo dejé como está en el código de la pregunta sin agregar position:absolute, simplemente agregué un <div> para toda la tabla con el justify-content-center como dijo Aprendiz y me funcionó

Answer (score 5):

Hice una prueba con el código que publicaste y no se muestra así.  Se muestra centrado pero un poco hacia la izquierda, lo que corregí quitando esto del css:

```
table{
   position:relative;
   margin:auto;
   width:100%;
   /*left:-15%*/;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenté lo que dices pero la tabla se sigue desplazando a la derecha por la cantidad de caracteres que tiene la contraseña, como muestro en la imagen de la pregunta

Answer (score 5):

La tabla se está corriendo hacia la derecha de la página porque estás asignando un ancho fijo a la sección que contiene tu tabla:

```
section {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width:400px;
        }
```

Adicional a esto, te recomiendo no incluir varias columnas dentro de otras cuando no es necesario.

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

table thead tr th {
  padding: 10px;
}

table tbody tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      background: #0F3E45;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: white;
    }
    
    h3 {
      color: white;
    }
    
    p {
      color: white;
    }
    
    th {
      color: white;
    }
    
    td {
      color: white;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 24%;
      line-height: 50px;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    nav ul li a:hover {
      color: green;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    section {
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;     
    }
    
    .form-group {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar-dark .navbar-brand:hover {
      color: lightblue;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    section form input#usuarioRegistro {
      text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    
    section h2 {
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-start">       
            <h2>USUARIOS</h2>          
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class=row>
            <div class="col-12">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Contraseña</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Editar</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Borrar</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>fe276cd31d01cfb5d58c8ad51ca9b346</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Editar</td>
                    <td>Borrar</td>
                  </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td>admin</td>
                    <td>739d3d81d6233eef69373043c429a6c2</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Editar</td>
                    <td>Borrar</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="views/js/validarRegistro.js"></script>
  <script src="views/js/validarIngreso.js"></script>
  <script src="views/js/validarEdicion.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! lo tomaré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

al parecer tu problema esta en esta lineas de estilo.

```css
table{
                position:relative;
                margin:auto;
                width:100%;
                left:-15%;
            }
```

```html
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>


<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-12 ">
                    <h2>USUARIOS</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class=row>
                    <div class="col" >
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Contraseña</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Editar</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Borrar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>a1</td>
                                  <td>b1</td>
                                  <td>c1</td>
                                  <td>d1</td>
                                  <td>e1</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>a2</td>
                                  <td>b2</td>
                                  <td>c2</td>
                                  <td>d2</td>
                                  <td>e2</td>
                              </tr>
                              
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te refieres a que quite table{.....}? si lo quito del código, sigue pasando lo mismo que muestro en la imagen